# Why does aws s3 cp command not transfering the files through the ip network, however it works only in the local directory?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have module where I need to send the zip files to other ip network via aws s3 cp so now I just test my command if it works to my aws command line and to my local directory but it works. the file from s3 bucket transfer to my path that i put **C:\xampp\htdocs** now the confuse thing here when i try to change the path where i need to send the files via ip address. the files is not transferring and I really don't know why it not works via ip address. and I can't find any solution what it called to that function.

My programming language that I used is laravel: so i created a function for sending zip files to the other network.I will share to you guys the sample codes that I made.

**This function is working:**

```
public function send_zip_files_to_store() {



    exec('aws s3 cp s3://compexp/11-11-2019/01150exp.zip  C:\xampp\htdocs');

    return response()->json('success download');

}
```

**This function is not working transferring the files via ip address:**

```
 public function send_zip_files_to_store() {



    exec('aws s3 cp s3://compexp/11-11-2019/01150exp.zip  \\xx.xx.x.xxx/c/');

    return response()->json('success download');

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, when you have two backslashes, they resolve to a single backslash.  So, your path `\\xx.xx.x.xxx` ends up like `\xx.xx.x.xxx`, which isn't what you want.

In your string literal, you'll need four backslashes if you want it to be like two:

```
exec('aws s3 cp s3://compexp/11-11-2019/01150exp.zip  \\\\xx.xx.x.xxx/c/');
```

Comment: @SoulAiker Cool, glad it's working!  If you want, you can click that checkmark next to the answer to mark it as the accepted answer to close the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again @Brad

Comment: hi brad sorry for the disturbed as i said it works, however if i use that on linux  the transferring files is not working. it works your code in windows only

Comment: @SoulAiker Linux cannot access Windows network paths.  You must mount them to the filesystem.  Use `smbclient`.